# I can't get my ip on android device although internet permission is set on manifest

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-manifest

I'm using eclipse + android SDK on ubuntu, and running a test activity server using sockets.

My Manifest has internet permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="INTERNET"/>
```

But when I look for my IP on the device using:

```
    // gets the ip address of your device
private String getLocalIpAddress() 
{
    try 
    {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) 
        {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) 
            {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) { return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(); }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (SocketException ex) 
    {
        Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

I get an exception on Logcat:

```
Java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

Tag: MyActivity, but i have internet permission on the manifest.

If i try to put the IP manually, when i use sockets, i get also the exception with TAG: System.err

Some ideas about the problem??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should check your manifest file more carefully where you placed that uses-permissions Tag. I've just tested the code and it worked fine.

Comment: The permission work on other project, i think is in the correct place. But thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you must write the permission this way in the manifest xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

instead of only "INTERNET". Try it just in case.

Comment: Yes, the problem was that. Thanks a lot Jav_Rock. I'm a dumb.